# can't prefill a kendo-inputfield

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

i can't prefill one of my inputfields and i don't know why. (btw, i'm using kendo / angular js in this project). this is my inputfield

```
<input id="selection" class="form-element-small" kendo-auto-complete
k-data-text-field="'city_name'" ng-model="autocomplete" k-data-source="cities"
 k-placeholder="'Enter a city'"/>
```

and this is the scriptcode that fails:

```
var city_name_pre = window.localStorage.getItem('city_name');
if (city_name_pre != null) {
    console.log(city_name_pre);
    console.log($('#selection').val());
    $('#selection').val(city_name_pre);
    console.log($('#selection').val());
}
```

first console.log says "boston". second console.log says "" (well.. of course ;) ). third console.log says "boston" like it should.

but the actual inputfield is still empty and the inspector in the browser says value="" as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are pushing values to the ng-model, doesn't help?

```
var city_name_pre = window.localStorage.getItem('city_name');
if (city_name_pre != null) {
    $scope.autocomplete = city_name_pre;
}
```

Comment: omg.. of course! thank you very much.
now i'm feeling a bit ashamed :(